# Enter a custom message (optional) in bounty becomes compulsory

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bounty

I tried to apply a bounty in a question, so in custom message i write which is i think optional, but it says some more to go...
so i think to clean all the message and apply bounty without message. but the Start Bounty disable.[image]

Comment: What browser are you on? I can't reproduce this (on Chrome 36.0.1985.125)

Comment: chrome 33.0.1750.152 in ubuntu 12.02

Comment: Did you try closing the modal window and starting over?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue - and I see you were [finally successful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25117468/applying-future-where-can-be-exception-comes) in starting a bounty.  How many more tries did it take?

Comment: Repro on Safari 7. +1. I ran into this bug many times...